# Abrir PDF atualizado

Tags: php, html, html5

Bom, tenho um sistema em PHP que constrói um PDF. Após isso, tenho um link comum do html que abre o pdf na tela normalmente, até aí tudo ok.

Porem se eu modifico o conteúdo do PDF, e dou o comando para o sistema reconstruí-lo com estas novas informações, ao clicar no link para abrir, ele abre o pdf antigo, só consigo visualizar o novo se der um "F5".

Alguém sabe uma alternativa para sempre abrir o arquivo já atualizado e não a versão de cache?

PS: o link abre o arquivo já pronto que está salvo no servidor.

Comment: tente colocar uma variável que sempre mude no link, ex: `www.meusite.com/arquivo.pdf?n=093904`. Assim, toda vez que alterar este `?n=` ele não irá encontrar nada em cache, e irá abrir o pdf novo

Comment: Isso deve funcionar.

Mas não é exatamente o que queria, enfim, se não conseguir outra forma vou aplica-la. Obrigado Leonardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma abordagem melhor seria usar os `header()` para informar o navegador que o conteúdo da requisição não deve ter cache.

```php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies
```

Fonte: [Preventing cache of inline PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714885/preventing-cache-of-inline-pdf)

Comment: Era isso que precisava, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas formas de solucionar este problema, desde html a javascript. No entanto a mais fácil seria criar um link variável, sendo pelo nome do arquivo pdf ou por um parâmetro:

```
echo '<a href="files/pdfs/filename.pdf?q='.microtime(true).'">PDF</a>';
```

A forma mais sergura seria realmente sempre alterar o nome do arquivo pdf. No entanto não é muito prático ou legal. Um parâmetro na URL funciona em praticamente 99% das vezes

Fonte: [stackoverflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225152/google-chrome-cache-pdf-files)